# Javafx problem with setting multiple JFXtextfield based on JSON response from an api

Tags: java, http, javafx, httprequest

I am building a javafx project that is to retrieve from an api in json and automatically set an item Name and Price upon entering an id. I can retrieve the name and set it to a JFXTextfield but cannot set the selling price. My code is as below

```
package tech.controller;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

public class newSale {
    @FXML
    public JFXTextField id;

    @FXML
    public  JFXTextField quantity;

    @FXML
    public  JFXTextField name;

    @FXML
    public JFXTextField sellingPrice;

    @FXML
    public void getItemDetail(KeyEvent keyEvent) {

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("http://localhost:3001/postMongo/id-"+id.getText())).GET().build();
        client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
               .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
               .thenApply(newSale::parse).thenAccept(name::setText);
    }




    public static String parse(String responseBody) {

        JSONArray posts = new JSONArray(responseBody);
            JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(0);
            String nameItem = post.getString("name");
            return nameItem;
    }
    public static String parseSelling(String responseBody) {

        JSONArray posts = new JSONArray(responseBody);
        JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(0);
        Object enumId = post.get("_id");
        String nameItem = post.getString("name");
        Double sellingPrice = post.getDouble("sellingPrice");


        return sellingPrice.toString();
    }
}
```

I tried to parse again and return it to the selling price textfield as below but to no avail

```
client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
               .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
               .thenApply(newSale::parse).thenAccept(name::setText)
        .thenApply(newSale::parseSelling).thenAccept(sellingPrice::setText);
```

Is there any way this can be achieved

the JSON response is as below

```
[{
    "_id": "123",
    "name": "Waiwai",
    "sellingPrice": 25,
    "wholesalePrice": 24,
    "quantity": 12,
    "type": "small",
    "totalSold": 0
}]
```

I can achieve this like this

```
 HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("http://localhost:3001/postMongo/id-" + id.getText())).GET().build();
HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()); 
JSONArray item = new JSONArray(response.body());
JSONObject itemObject = item.getJSONObject(0);
            String getName = itemObject.getString("name");
            name.setText(getName); 
            double getSellingPrice = itemObject.getDouble("sellingPrice");
            double getWholesalePrice = 
            itemObject.getDouble("wholesalePrice");
            String sellingPriceFinal = Double.toString(getSellingPrice);
            sellingPrice.setText(sellingPriceFinal);
            String typeItem = itemObject.getString("type");
            type.setText(typeItem);
```

Is there anyway to do this in async httpclient request

Comment: Post a sample JSON response in the question

Comment: [mcve] please ..